# Separate year and date in biblatex and add online-note for @WWW

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `biblatex` with the `ext-authoryear` style. Now I have following problem.

When an entry has both date and year, then the date is displayed right behind the author, like in the following example:

> Neuhetzki, Thorsten (8. Mai 2017): GSM, UMTS & LTE: Mobilfunkfrequenzen
>       in Deutschland im Überblick, herausgegeben von teltarif.de Onlineverlag
>       GmbH, url: https://www.teltarif.de/frequenzen-mobilfunk-netzbetreiber-uebersicht-lte-2017/news/68488.html (Abruf vom
>       27. 07. 2018)

What I want to have now is to separate the date and the year to have following result:

> Neuhetzki, Thorsten (**2017**): GSM, UMTS & LTE: Mobilfunkfrequenzen
>       in Deutschland im Überblick, herausgegeben von teltarif.de Onlineverlag
>       GmbH, **8. Mai 2017**, url: https://www.teltarif.de/frequenzen-mobilfunk-netzbetreiber-uebersicht-lte-2017/news/68488.html (Abruf vom
>       27. 07. 2018)

The changes are marked bold, but this is just to visualize which entries I want to change.

Does anyone has an idea how to get this?

---

Due to the fact to create just one entry every 20 Minutes I'd like to ask one more thing.

After the Title of an @WWW entry there should be a [online], like

> Neuhetzki, Thorsten (2017): GSM, UMTS & LTE: Mobilfunkfrequenzen
>       in Deutschland im Überblick **[online]**, herausgegeben von teltarif.de Onlineverlag
>       GmbH, 8. Mai 2017, url: https://www.teltarif.de/frequenzen-mobilfunk-netzbetreiber-uebersicht-lte-2017/news/68488.html (Abruf vom
>       27. 07. 2018)

As mentioned above, the bold is just to visualize what I want to achieve (without the bold stuff).

Edit1: Found a solution for the [online], referring to [BibLaTeX: How to remove dot in modified field format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369558/biblatex-how-to-remove-dot-in-modified-field-format/369562)

Thanks to @moewe this was the way to go:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[www,online]{title}{\emph{#1}\setunit{\space}\printtext{[online]}}
```

Comment: Please try to provide an MWE with your questions. It is fairly clear what you are after, but it is much easier for me to test my solutions if I have code to test it with. The current state shows that you have applied customisations already, I can only guarantee that my solution and your customisations are compatible if I get to see the code that you have already. Posting an MWE also shows that you care about the time of the people trying to help you, because you don't let them replicate what you already have.

Comment: And please ask only one question per question. There is absolutely no problem with asking five question on one day, provided the questions are good. But it can be a pain for the people trying to help you and future visitors who are looking for answer if there are several only tangentially related issues in one question. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864.

Comment: @moewe as your solution which u posted below works i think a MWE is not necessary anymore. post this the next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `mergedate` option, documentation can be found in the style documentation of `authoryear` and friends: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/50-style-authoryear-biber.pdf

You probably want

```
mergedate=basic,
```

but maybe you want the more radical `mergedate=false` or `mergedate=minimum`. The default is `mergedate=compact`.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber, mergedate=basic]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{markey}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Markey, Nicolas (2005). Tame the BeaST. The B to X of BibTeX. Version 1.3. 16. Okt. 2005. url: http://mirror.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf (besucht am 01.10.2006).]